# Puedo sumar un campo que guarda 1 y 0 separado por punto y coma

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo que realizar una suma en `MySQL` de un campo llamado asistencia que guarda `0` y `1` dependiendo si asiste o no

```
taller       personas                    asistencia
65           31;42;58 (idUsuario)        1;0;1;1;1
```

hay forma de sumar los valores de la asistencia para totalizar el número de participantes.

Comment: ¿Cuáles son las tablas y las columnas de tu base de datos? ¿Tenes una sola tabla con las columnas taller, personas y asistencia? Si es así, tu base de datos tiene un claro problema de diseño.

Comment: Mira la tabla taller está relacionada con el id de personas  y el campo de asistencia que pertenece a la tabla taller se guarda 0 o 1 dependiendo si la persona asistió o no pero solo necesito saber si por medio de mySQL puedo hacer que se sumen esos 1 de asistencia

Comment: No se si entiendo... puedes separar el campo asistencia mediante los `;` y luego contar cuantos son unos. Pero esto lo tendrias que hacer con php o el lenguaje que uses.

Comment: La pregunta clave es ¿por qué lo guardas así? ¿hay algún motivo concreto para romper la normalización? Se puede hacer lo que pides, pero seria más recomendable que normalices tu base de datos. Mínimo en 1FN.

Comment: exactamente, los puedo separar pero a la hora de contar sólo los 1, no he podido, con las consultas que he hecho solo me arroja el numero 1

Answer (score 2):

### Normalización

Consiste en un proceso en el cual se aplican reglas sobre cada una de las tablas para evitar la redundancia de datos, disminuir problemas al actualizar los datos y para proteger la integridad referencial de los datos.

#### Problemas

La estructura de tu base de datos tal cual esta ahora solo te va a traer problemas y dolores de cabeza.

- Es imposible asegurar la integridad referencial de los registros, que en español quiere decir que no vas a podes saber a ciencia cierta si la persona o el taller existe en tu base de datos.
- Cualquier interacción con la base de datos te va a llevar muchos más pasos de lo que normalmente llevaría, como tener que recorrer la cadena `31;42;58` para encontrar un valor.
- y así podría seguir ad infinitum..

#### Solución

- Crear una tabla taller en donde se guarde el id (clave primaria) y el nombre del mismo.
- Crear una tabla personas en donde se guarde el dni (clave primaria), nombre, etc.
- Crear una tabla inscripto que guarde la relación que existe entre los talleres y las personas, es decir, que almacene las dos claves foráneas tanto del taller como de la persona que asiste al mismo y una columna para saber si asistió o no al taller.

La estructura quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
+-----------+    +------------+    +-----------+
+ Taller    +    + Inscripto  +    + Persona   +
+-----------+    +------------+    +-----------+
+ ID_taller +    + ID_taller  +    + DNI       +
+ Nombre    +    + DNI        +    + Nombre    +
+-----------+    + Asistio    +    +-----------+
                 +------------+
```

---

Podes usar la clausula `COUNT` que devuelve la cantidad de registros de una consulta `SELECT`.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cantidad
FROM inscripto
WHERE asistio = 1;
```

[Documentación (en inglés)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html)

Comment: ya lo intente y me arroja un 1

Comment: @user54766 Edite la respuesta, espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 2):

Al preguntar sobre bases de datos es importante mostrar el diseño para obtener respuestas más adecuadas. De lo contrario, tendremos que *imaginar* un modelo de datos idóneo.

Yo imagino tu modelo más o menos así:

- Una tabla `inscripciones` que gestiona las personas inscritas, en qué taller, y las asistencias
- Una tabla `personas` que guarda los datos de las personas
- Una tabla `talleres` que no aparece aquí, pero que guardaría las particularidades de cada taller

En el ejemplo muestro un contador de asistentes y de no asistentes por taller.  También muestro una lista de las personas que asistieron y de las que no, para saber quienes son los negligentes :)

Igualmente puedes obtener el total de inscritos, diciendo quien asistió o no, etc. Como podrás apreciar es un modelo flexible. Imaginemos un mismo taller que se desarrolla en días o sesiones distintos y haya que tener un control de asistencias por sesión, sería muy fácil adaptar este modelo, sea agregando una o dos columnas a la tabla `inscripciones`... o trasladando la columna `taller_id` a la tabla `sesiones` y colocando a su vez una columna `sesion_id` en la tabla `inscripciones`...  Cuando se crea un diseño de datos hay que pensar también en las futuras evoluciones del mismo.

Espero te sirva.

#### `Código:` [`ver demo`](http://rextester.com/JHD24353)

```
CREATE TABLE inscripciones (
          taller_id   INT,
          persona_id  INT,
          asistio     BOOLEAN
        );

 INSERT INTO inscripciones (taller_id, persona_id, asistio) 
             VALUES 
             (65,1,TRUE),
             (65,2,TRUE),
             (65,3,FALSE),
             (65,4,TRUE),
             (65,5,FALSE),
             (65,6,TRUE),
             (65,7,TRUE)
        ;


 CREATE TABLE personas (
          persona_id  SERIAL,
          persona_nom VARCHAR(50)
        );

 INSERT INTO personas (persona_nom) 
             VALUES 
             ('Pedro'),
             ('Santiago'),
             ('Juan'),
             ('María'),
             ('Andrés'),
             ('Magdalena'),
             ('Sara')
        ;

-- Asistentes por taller

SELECT taller_id, COUNT(asistio) asistentes 
FROM inscripciones WHERE asistio=TRUE GROUP BY taller_id;

-- No Asistentes por taller


SELECT taller_id, COUNT(asistio) asistentes 
FROM inscripciones WHERE asistio=FALSE GROUP BY taller_id;

-- Asistentes al taller 65
SELECT p.persona_nom FROM personas p
INNER JOIN inscripciones i ON p.persona_id=i.persona_id
WHERE taller_id=65 AND asistio=TRUE;


-- No Asistentes al taller 65
SELECT p.persona_nom FROM personas p
INNER JOIN inscripciones i ON p.persona_id=i.persona_id
WHERE taller_id=65 AND asistio=FALSE;
```

---

#### `Resultado:`

```
--Total Asistentes

    taller_id   asistentes
1   65          5

--Total No Asistentes

    taller_id   no-asistentes
1   65          2



--Lista Asistentes

    persona_nom
1   Pedro
2   Santiago
3   María
4   Magdalena
5   Sara


--Lista Negligentes :)

    persona_nom
1   Juan
2   Andrés
```

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez te sirva esta instrucción. En este ejemplo la cadena "1;0;1;1;1" tenes que reemplazar por asistencia.

```
select length (replace( replace( "1;0;1;1;1" , ";" , "") , "0","" ) ) as cantasitencia
```

lo que hace la instruccion es, con los replace quita el (;) y los (0) dejando solamente los uno (1), es decir "1111" para luego contar la longitud.

Comment: @user54766 lo que hace la instruccion es, con los replace quita el (;) y el (0) dejando solamente los uno. Es decir "1111" para luego contar la longitud.